# __gfortran_transfer_integer_write undefined for Mac OSX.6.8 - gfortran

Tags: macos, gfortran, fortran77

I am having trouble installing an ancient F77 program on a mac (OS 10.6.8).  When I compile (with gfortran), I get the following errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "__gfortran_transfer_integer_write", referenced from:
  _abfind_ in Abfind.o
  _binplot_ in Binplot.o
  _binplotprep_ in Binplotprep.o
  _blends_ in Blends.o
  _chabund_ in Chabund.o
  _curve_ in Curve.o
  _damping_ in Damping.o
  ...
  "__gfortran_transfer_real_write", referenced from:
  _abfind_ in Abfind.o
  _abpop_ in Abpop.o
  _binplot_ in Binplot.o
  _binplotprep_ in Binplotprep.o
  _blends_ in Blends.o
  _calmod_ in Calmod.o
  _chabund_ in Chabund.o
  ...
```

etcetera... Any ideas where to look?

Comment: It's obviously a link problem.  You might get (better) answers if you share with us how you are compiling and linking the program.

Comment: This error comes from using gcc to link fortran programs.  Just use gfortran to link it and it should be OK.  Other possibilities: Are you building the fortran code with CC or FC?  Is FC defined as gcc or gfortran?